# FFPlay interface in C#?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I recently found a way to convert video's through the FFMpeg converter through command line, but ive recently been interested in making a video player! and i heard that VLC player and various other systems use FFPlay, and i dont know anything about it! so i have some main points of interest..

### Questions:

- What exactly does the ffplay.exe do?
- If it allows me to stream videos, how would i create an interface to C# to use that
- How would i display the video on a windows forms app.

If one of those is not possible, im welcome to other alternatives.. or even perhaps writing my own. Suggestions welcome! :)

Edit: im looking for possible solutions with a framework requirement of 3 or below, and also would perfer to not make them install anything additional to my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not expert but based on what I know,

1. You can perhaps look at DirectShow technology for developing your video player as there are managed lib such as [directshow.net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/index.html) available for it.
2. To my knowledge, FFPlay is GUI on top of [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffmpeg) libraries - the main part of FFmpeg is audio/video codec library supporting many formats including MPEG-4 implementation.
3. To use FFmpeg via DirectShow, you need another component known as [ffdshow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffdshow).

Comment: It looks like because ffdshow would require the user to have to reconfiqure things on their computer before my program would work, this is not an optiona

Comment: Yes - ffdshow will be a separate component. Players based on DirectShow (e.g. Windows Media Player) rely on external codecs for supporting formats. User may have different codec for x format than ffmpeg and it would work. I believe that VLC Player installs many codecs so that it could support multiple formats.